# HTACCESS friendly url and allow GET method

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, seo

My code is

```
 Options -Multiviews

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.html$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

If I access

```
mysite.com/name-of-category.html
```

it works, but if I access

```
mysite.com/name-of-category.html?anything=something
```

it shows the webpage but `$_GET["anything"]` shows nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify an option called [QSA or 'Query String Append'](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.html$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It will ensure that the original query strings are also included as part of your new URL.

Comment: Note that there is no space between flags `[L, QSA]` will **not** work :) (Answerer has it correct - no space between `[L,QSA]`)